# linking error/conflict for SendMessageA method

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services

I have built the aws-cpp-sdk the following way:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DBUILD_ONLY="s3;sqs;sns"
```

and after that I ran:

```
MSBuild.exe INSTALL.vcxproj
```

Which produced the following files in the "*C:\Program Files\aws-cpp-sdk-all*" directory:

```
aws-c-common.dll
aws-c-event-stream.dll
aws-checksums.dll
aws-cpp-sdk-access-management.dll
aws-cpp-sdk-access-management.lib
aws-cpp-sdk-cognito-identity.dll
aws-cpp-sdk-cognito-identity.lib
aws-cpp-sdk-core.dll
aws-cpp-sdk-core.lib
aws-cpp-sdk-iam.dll
aws-cpp-sdk-iam.lib
aws-cpp-sdk-sns.dll
aws-cpp-sdk-sns.lib
aws-cpp-sdk-sqs.dll
aws-cpp-sdk-sqs.lib

aws-c-common.lib
aws-c-event-stream.lib
aws-checksums.lib
```

along with the *include* directory. I have included all the headers and all the libraries:

```
#include <aws/core/Aws.h>
#include <aws/core/auth/AWSCredentials.h>
#include <aws/core/client/ClientConfiguration.h>
#include <aws/core/utils/logging/DefaultLogSystem.h>
#include <aws/core/utils/logging/AWSLogging.h>
#include <aws/sns/model/PublishRequest.h>
#include <aws/sns/model/PublishResult.h>
#include <aws/s3/model/ListObjectsRequest.h>
#include <aws/core/utils/Outcome.h>
#include <aws/s3/model/Bucket.h>
#include <aws/sqs/SQSClient.h>
#include <aws/sqs/model/SendMessageRequest.h>

#pragma comment( lib, "aws-cpp-sdk-core.lib"         )
#pragma comment( lib, "aws-c-common.lib"         )
#pragma comment( lib, "aws-c-event-stream.lib"   )
#pragma comment( lib, "aws-checksums.lib"        )

#pragma comment( lib, "aws-cpp-sdk-core.lib"     )
#pragma comment( lib, "aws-cpp-sdk-iam.lib"  )
#pragma comment( lib, "aws-cpp-sdk-sqs.lib"      )
#pragma comment( lib, "aws-cpp-sdk-sns.lib"      )
#pragma comment( lib, "aws-cpp-sdk-cognito-identity.lib"         )
#pragma comment( lib, "aws-cpp-sdk-access-management.lib"        )

...

Aws::SQS::SQSClient                 sqs;
Aws::SQS::Model::SendMessageRequest sm_req;

sm_req.SetQueueUrl( "https://sqs.amazonaws.com/123123" );
sm_req.SetMessageBody( stringJSONFormatted.c_str() );

auto sm_out = sqs.SendMessage(sm_req);
if (sm_out.IsSuccess())
    Logger::Log( "Message sent successfully to the AWS SQS" );
else
    Logger::Log( "FAILED to send message send to AWS SQS" );
```

But whenever I build this I get:

```
__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual class Aws::Utils::Outcome<class Aws::SQS::Model::SendMessageResult,class Aws::Client::AWSError<enum Aws::SQS::SQSErrors> > 
__cdecl Aws::SQS::SQSClient::SendMessageA(class Aws::SQS::Model::SendMessageRequest const &)const 
(__imp_?SendMessageA@SQSClient@SQS@Aws@@UEBA?AV?$Outcome@VSendMessageResult@Model@SQS@Aws@@V?$AWSError@W4SQSErrors@SQS@Aws@@@Client@4@@Utils@3@AEBVSendMessageRequest@Model@23@@Z) 
fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I tried everything I could find, I even re-built the library many times with different arguments, but still the same problem persists. it seems it has something do with **AWS::SQSClient::SendMessageA** name conflicting with some kind of Windows method (but I'm probably wrong). There was one solution which stated, if I define this before the *AWS* headers, it should build:

```
#undef GetObject
```

but still the same error. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the Windows system headers define the macro `SendMessage` to expand to either `SendMessageA` or `SendMessageW` depending on the existence of the `UNICODE` macro.

It does this for a *lot* of functions in the Windows API, which of course means that there will be clashes with other code using symbols that turn out to be macros in Windows.

One possible solution is to `#undef SendMessage` after `#include <windows.h>`. Which might not be possible if the code you try to build comes from a third party.

Comment: Thank you very much! After being stuck for countless hours I was able to build it successfully!! Now I get a runtime exception: Assertion Failed: s_HttpClientFactory, not sure if it's related or not, will look into it

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at [this blog post](https://blogs.msmvps.com/gdicanio/2015/06/22/the-sticky-preprocessor-based-tchar-model-part-2-wheres-my-function/) for a detailed explanation.

You may try with:

```
#undef SendMessage
```

*before* including the AWS headers (similarly to the `#undef GetObject` you cited in your question).